# Stetting environment variable in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to set an environment variable for the first time (Windows 8.1, 64 bit) and I keep getting this: error: 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

What do I do to fix?

Comment: I got answer to this question. In Windows environment you use Set command, not Export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to this question. In Windows environment you use Set command, not Export

Answer (score 2):

In Windows environment you use Set command, not Export